# When page first loaded or refreshed api post call don't wok well first time but after toggling button one or two times it works well

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a toggle button in my page, when it is OFF it sends 0 value to my post API and when button is ON it sends 1 in API. But the problem is when project is loaded or refreshed by toggling the button state value doesn't change first time but by toggling one or two times it works well after. code is given below any solution would be great help. thanks.

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

this.state = {
checked: false,
value: 0
};
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

handleChange() {
        if (this.state.checked === true) {
        this.setState({ value:1, checked: false })
        }
        else if (this.state.checked == false) {
            this.setState({ value:0, checked: true })
        }
        const article = { 
            "all_value":this.state.value
             };
        const headers = { 
            'api-key': 'key',
            
        };
         axios.post('url', article, { headers })
            .then(function(response) {console.log(response);
            })
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is only applicable where the component is functional. An example is below to change class component to functional component.**

You're calling `setState()` and then using the value immediately. That will cause the component to rerender, with the correct `state` but by that point you've made the call with the previous `state`.

I would suggest the `axios.post` call is inside a useEffect hook, to detect changes

```
this.state = {
checked: false,
value: 0
};
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const article = {
        "all_value": this.state.value
    }
    const headers = {
        'api-key': 'key',

    };

    axios.post('url', article, { headers })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
}, [this.state])
```

This will use setState to trigger a rerender with the new values, and then useEffect will trigger seeing the values have changed, and make a new call to the API.

EDIT: The `this.state` needed to have `[ ]`

**Class based component to functional component**

Taking the example from the question, it's trivial to convert a `class component` to a `functional component`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
const Dashboard = (props) => {

    const [dashboardState, setDashboardState] = useState({
        checked: false,
        value: 0
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const article = {
            "all_value": dashboardState.value
        }
        const headers = {
            'api-key': 'key',

        };

        axios.post('url', article, { headers })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
    }, [setDashboardState])

    const handleChange = () => {

        dashboardState.checked ? 
            setDashboardState({ value: 1, checked: false }) : setDashboardState({ value: 0, checked: true })

        const article = {
            "all_value": dashboardState.value
        };
        const headers = {
            'api-key': 'key',

        };
        axios.post('url', article, { headers })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
    };

    return (
        <div>Do your rendering / use handleChange() down here</div>
    )
}
export default Dashboard
```

Comment: i have used useEffect like you said but i'm getting this warning: React Hook useEffect was passed a dependency list that is not an array literal. This means we can't statically verify whether you've passed the correct dependencies.

Comment: I've edited the answer. You are right - it should be an array passed, containing ```[this.state]```

Comment: i have put it in array but get new warning of: React Hook useEffect has a complex expression in the dependency array. Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically checked.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps).

Comment: in this method i'm getting this error:Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: i'm using the class component and useEffect hook can only be called in functional component. so is there any other way which i can use in class component??

Comment: Good shout for that. I will update the answer once I've had a think

Comment: is there a way to do this in class component?

Comment: I've added an example to show class -> functional component. *I have not tested it, this is an example*.